# How to promisify a function which contains no callback parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am currently working an API/router which is to be integrated in the user's own web server. My code will do its required work but also allow the user to implement their own logic afterwards such as in this snippet: `myApi.on('action', (err, result, req, res) => {/*user's logic here*/})`.

By design, my code will not end the response if the user decides to override the default behavior and implement their own logic. This is to allow the request and response to fall through to the next middleware function if desired by the user.

The control flow I desire is:

1. Run my initial route logic
2. Run the user's custom logic
3. Pass control to the next middleware function if response hasn't ended

My issue arises when the user wants to implement any async logic. I have no way of allowing the user's custom logic to conclude before passing control onto the next middleware function. I believe it is because of the interface I have set up. I desire as little busywork as possible to be performed by the user. This means I would prefer not passing the user some equivalent of a `callback()` or `next()` function which they would need to call at every endpoint of their logic (as my router involves a number of different routes).

I've looked into promise wrappers such as [promisify-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-node), but they seem only capable of wrapping functions which take a callback as their final argument. I've also considered requiring the user return a promise from their custom implementation, but that goes against my desire of not requiring busywork/boilerplate code.

Is there any way using promises -- or any other construct -- I can deal with this async issue without having to pain the user?

Comment: How do you define that a request is ended?

Comment: @Amit, seems I switched request and response. I'd check if the**response** was finished by checking the res.finished tag.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot promisify a function that does not take a callback. Such a function either isn't asynchronous or doesn't provide you any way to know when it's finished - you're out of luck.

> My issue arises when the user wants to implement any async logic.

Just require the user to pass a function that returns a promise if he wants to implement something asynchronous. It will probably do him a favour having to work with promises anyway :-)

```
const myApi = {
    on(name, fn) {
        Promise.resolve(result) // or whenever you need to run the user logic
        .then(result => 
            fn(req, result) // or whatever you want to pass
        )
        .then(customresult => {
            res.write(customresult); // or whatever you want to do with its result
        });
    }
};

myApi.on('action', (req, result) => {
    // user's logic here
    // throw exceptions
    // return values
    // return promises for values
    // or whatever the user needs to do
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you would inspect the value the users' custom function returns. If it is a *promise-like* object then you can wait for it to resolve before moving on. This is equivalent to passing a `next` function to the users' custom middle ware.

In your example the user(s) would use your API like so:

```
myApi.on('action', (err, result, req, res) => {
  return myPromiseAwareAsyncFunction();
})
```

And in your code:

```
let userMiddleWare = lookupNextActionHandler();
let result = userMiddleWare(err, result, req, res);
// Wrap any value (promise or not) in a promise
Promise.resolve(result)
  .then(result => {
    // Move on to next middle ware
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1); // Or what ever you use
                     // to end the middle ware chain.
  });
```

If you wish to offer both promises *and* a `next` callback you could do something like this:

```
let userMiddleWare = lookupNextActionHandler();
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  function next(err) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  }
  let result = userMiddleWare(err, result, req, res, next);
  Promise.resolve(result).then(resolve).catch(reject);
})
.then(result => {
  // Move on to next middle ware
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1); // Or what ever you use
                   // to end the middle ware chain.
});
```

Since promises can only handle one resolution and ignores further incantations after set this will work and which ever the user uses (`next` or return a Promise) will work.